# Rename entire files in a folder

Tags: terminal

I have a folder and the file names are starting with **db_filename** i need to change this prefix db to sd but file-name should be the same there is 6768 files are there is there any command available to rename these files. i tried such commands in terminal but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Show us your failing commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use python to solve your problem easily, with the following script.

```
import os
parent = '/home/username/Tmp/dbfolder' # change it to your folder
for p,d,f in os.walk(parent):
  for filename in f:
    if filename.startswith('db'):
      path_ori = os.path.join(p,filename)
      path_new = os.path.join(p,'sd'+filename[2:])
      os.rename(path_ori, path_new)
```

you can paste the code into your texteditor, change the `parent` with your folder name, and save the file using name like `rename.py`
Then in terminal, type `python rename.py`. Done.
Of course, fisrt you should make sure that you have python on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If using [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) (or `linux` tools under windows) :

```
rename 's/^db/sd/' db_*
```

rename is https://metacpan.org/module/rename & is installed by default on many distros.